# How to get type of HTTP POST data?

Tags: c#, http-post, fiddlercore

[image]

In the picture above, I have `Request Body` of a `POST` request with `FiddlerCore dll`.

Here is how I capture it:

```
private void FiddlerApplication_AfterSessionComplete(Session sess)
{
        string requestBody = "";

        if (sess.oRequest != null)
        {
            if (sess.oRequest.headers != null)
            {
                requestBody = sess.GetRequestBodyAsString();
            }
        }
}
```

However, I would only need to capture it in the case it's parameters (2 last line on the picture) and in the other case I don't need to capture it.

I can filter it with `string`, it is what I do so far. However, what would be the proper way to do this?

**NOTE:** Each line on the picture is a different request, for a total of 5.

Comment: I think so, for the first 2 I have to be honest I have no idea what they are supposed to be... but if I'm interested in parameters, could I just skip them? I just made a test with Content-Type, and it seems that most of the ones I don't want don't possess Content-Type property

Comment: There is the first clue. Use that as a filter. If there is no content type then ignore it. Figure out the ones you do want and take those. What is the content type you do want

Comment: For the request I have to capture every POST request. However, I only display the body if they are parameter... looking at the property for now I see nothing unique to identify the requests I need to keep...

Comment: What is the content type of those with parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no content type then ignore it. Figure out the ones you do want and take those.

```
private void FiddlerApplication_AfterSessionComplete(Session sess) {
    if (sess == null || sess.oRequest == null || sess.oRequest.headers == null)
        return;

    // Ignore HTTPS connect requests or other non-POST requests
    if (sess.RequestMethod == "CONNECT" || sess.RequestMethod != "POST")
        return;

    var reqHeaders = sess.oRequest.headers.ToString(); //request headers  

    // Get the content type of the request
    var contentType = sess.oRequest["Content-Type"];

    // Lets assume you have a List<string> of approved content types.

    // Ignore requests that do not have a content type 
    // or are not in the approved list of types.
    if(contentType != null && !approvedContent.Any(c => contentType.Containes(c))
        return;    

    var reqBody = sess.GetRequestBodyAsString();//get the Body of the request

    //...other code.
}
```

Comment: thanks!! I just saw that all of those I want contain image/gif at least!! thanks so much!!!